# Autofocus remove

Tags: html, css

I have a form and I want to do a focus css the problem is on password input I cant disable autofocus I tried everything, autofocus="off",autofocus="false" but didnd work I search other answers here in SO and none of them solve my problem

```css
    * {
     margin : 0;
     padding : 0;
     border : 0;
    }

    body {
     background-color: #eee;
    }

    .form-login {
     width : 400px;
     height: auto;
     position : absolute;
     padding : 10px 25px;
     background-color: #ddd;
     left: 50%;
     top: 50%;
     transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
     border: none;
     border-top-right-radius: 5px;
     border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    }
    .login-logo {
     width: 125px;
     height : 125px;
     position: relative;
     border-radius : 125px;
     background: #ddd;
     margin: 0 auto;
     margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .input {
     width: 100%;
     height: 50px;
     background:gray;
     position: relative;
     margin:15px auto;
    }

    input[type="text"],
    input[type="password"]{
     width:100%;
     height:50px;
     position: relative;
     outline :none;
     border:1px solid gray;
     border-radius: 3px;
     font-size:16px;
     font-family: 'Questrial',sans-serif;
     padding-left: 30px;
          -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
                    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
           box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    }
    input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="password"]{
     border:2px solid #50C878;
    }
```

```html
<section class="container">
 <section class="form-login">
  <section class="login-logo">
   <img src="img/login-logo.png">
  </section>
   <form class="form" name="form" method="post" action="login-m.php">
    <section class ="input">
     <input type="text" name="utilizador" value="" placeholder="Insira o nome de utilizador"  required/><br>
     <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    </section>  
    <section class ="input"> 
     <input type="password" name="palavrachave" value="" placeholder="Insira a sua palavra-chave" autofocus="off"  required/><br>
     <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
    </section>
    <a href="#">Esqueceu a palavra-chave ?</a>
    <p> Nome de Utilizador e/ou Palavra-chave incorreto(s)</p>
    <input type="submit" name ="entrar" value="Entrar">
   </form>
 </section>
</section>
```

Comment: you should add `:focus` to your password style otherwise its always going to show the green border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is not on **autofocusing**. Remove `auto-focus` from HTML.

**It is the CSS which is giving you green border.**.

```
input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="password"]:focus{
    border:2px solid #50C878;
}
```

Since, first you are applying border to `password field` you are getting `green color`.

**The below is your solved code snippet**

```css
* {
     margin : 0;
     padding : 0;
     border : 0;
    }

    body {
     background-color: #eee;
    }

    .form-login {
     width : 400px;
     height: auto;
     position : absolute;
     padding : 10px 25px;
     background-color: #ddd;
     left: 50%;
     top: 50%;
     transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
     border: none;
     border-top-right-radius: 5px;
     border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    }
    .login-logo {
     width: 125px;
     height : 125px;
     position: relative;
     border-radius : 125px;
     background: #ddd;
     margin: 0 auto;
     margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .input {
     width: 100%;
     height: 50px;
     background:gray;
     position: relative;
     margin:15px auto;
    }

    input[type="text"],
    input[type="password"]{
     width:100%;
     height:50px;
     position: relative;
     outline :none;
     border:1px solid gray;
     border-radius: 3px;
     font-size:16px;
     font-family: 'Questrial',sans-serif;
     padding-left: 30px;
          -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
                    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
           box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    }
    input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="password"]:focus{
     border:2px solid #50C878;
    }
```

```html
<section class="container">
 <section class="form-login">
  <section class="login-logo">
   <img src="img/login-logo.png">
  </section>
   <form class="form" name="form" method="post" action="login-m.php">
    <section class ="input">
     <input type="text" name="utilizador" value="" placeholder="Insira o nome de utilizador"  required/><br>
     <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    </section>  
    <section class ="input"> 
     <input type="password" name="palavrachave" value="" placeholder="Insira a sua palavra-chave"   required/><br>
     <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
    </section>
    <a href="#">Esqueceu a palavra-chave ?</a>
    <p> Nome de Utilizador e/ou Palavra-chave incorreto(s)</p>
    <input type="submit" name ="entrar" value="Entrar">
   </form>
 </section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: - remove the `autofocus="off"` like the below

```
<input type="password" name="palavrachave" value="" 
 placeholder="Insira a sua palavra-chave" required/>
```

And change your password style to

```
input[type="text"]:focus, 
input[type="password"]:focus{
    border:2px solid #50C878;
}
```